# Chi Square Formula and Degrees of Freedom Questions

Tags: statistics, regression

I have a population sample with 200 points of data and 3 degrees of freedom so am I supposed to do a chi square formula with all 200 points of data? I believe that is what I'm supposed to do but I'm getting extremely high chi squared values and they are not on the chart at all. So am I supposed to use 200 degrees of freedom then?

I'm comparing predicted values for how much money a stock will make using different inputs from a multiple regression formula to the actual values and I'm very lost as to what to do to show how effective my predictions are.

1. Chi squared is only done for each input in a multiple regression formula or can I use it for the entire formula?
2. Someone mentioned the anova table and I looked this up and this might work but it doesn't seem to be used for multiple regression. Is this what I need or if not then what do I use to calculate how effective my multiple regression formula predictions are?

Comment: In is not clear what you intend to do. Are you trying to estimate a variance or standard deviation? I'm guessing that the 3 DF are related to estimating coefficients in the regression model. What chi-squared formula are you using? Separate from the regression if you are trying to estimate the variance of one of the variables, then that would use chi-squared with n - 1 = 199 DF.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo Yes I'm brand new to all of this stuff so I'm very sorry for being unclear. I'm testing out the expected values created with my multiple regression coefficients and I feel completely lost. I'm using the chi square formula found at http://formulas.tutorvista.com/math/chi-square-formula.html

How many degrees of freedom would I use if I'm estimating the variance of all 3 variables and comparing them to the actual value?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see how the chi-squared goodness-of-fit formula on the site to which you refer has anything to do with your multiple regression problem. It might help if you could be more specific about nature of the data, the anova table from the multiple regression output, what software you used, etc., someone could figure out how to help. But this question may just be a little beyond the level of detail we can handle on this site. If you are at or near a university, maybe you can talk to a statistical consultant.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo This data is dealing with the stock market. Using indicator information that has high t test results, I'm trying to input those items into a multiple regression formula to get expected growth for the stock. I wrote code in C# using Visual Studio. What is the chi squared formula used for then? I'm trying to get the pvalue for my multiple regression formula and I was told this is how I do it. I'm not sure what an anova table is but I will look into that. Do you need any more information?